# react dangerouslySetInnerHTML not re-rendering content

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here's my setup:

#### string-file.properties

```
someKey=This is my <span class="hello">{0}</span> string!
```

#### react-file.jsx

```
import stringAPI from 'string-file';    

class MyComponent extends Component {

    get content() {
        return { __html: stringAPI.someKey(this.props.word) };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.content} />
        );
    }
}
```

The argument to `stringAPI.someKey` get substituted for `{0}` in the string file and then the final html string is returned. My issue is that `this.props.word` is being updated while `MyComponent` is not being updated.

I read somewhere that dangerouslySetInnerHTML tells React that it doesn't need to watch the state of the component that the html is rendered in. If that's true, then I still need a way to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You could try setting the string as state in a parent component and passing it down as props to MyConponent

Answer (score 0):

Set the string as state. When receive new props (`componentWillReceiveProps`) do a `setState`. This should rerender the component. If that is not working make sure a unique key is set when the string changes. This also forces a rerender

Answer (score 0):

After adding unique key on div it's working fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).